# azure iotedge custom modules with raspberrypi

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge

i have written some azure custom IoT edge module in azure and i am able to run that module in ubuntu 18.04 and windows virtual machines.but when i am trying to run the module in Raspbian os all the modules is getting back off i will share my module architecture
this is my custom module details
[this is the image details of my module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxPgh.png)
i have build the modules with the help of azure quick start with this link help

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module#:~:text=In%20the%20command%20palette%2C%20enter,first%20module%20in%20the%20solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vs-code-develop-module#:%7E:text=In%20the%20command%20palette%2C%20enter,first%20module%20in%20the%20solution).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change your docker image's platform to Linux/arm32 instead of amd64, as Raspbian OS is an ARM 32-bit OS based on a Linux kernel (64-bit support is in beta, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi_OS)).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create images for multiple architectures at the same time: https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/